# Parse.com -- PFFile is null

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

So I'm retrieving an object that has a file as one of it's fields. In the Parse.com data browser the file is there and downloads. However, when I retrieve the object, `PFFile *wordlistFile = [object objectForKey:kWSWordlistFilesFileKey];` is returning null, and so `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` does nothing.

Here's the log of the object I'm retrieving. There is no reference to the file:

```
2013-12-03 12:07:10.635 WSPhoto[24958:a0b] object = <WordlistFiles:lRHFmHaPRg:(null)> {
    ACL = "<PFACL: 0xd445670>";
    language = Spanish;
}
```

And here's the full code. It appears I'm doing everything correctly based on some examples I've seen:

```
PFQuery* wordlistFilesQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kWSWordlistFilesClassKey];
[wordlistFilesQuery whereKey:kWSWordlistFilesLanguageKey equalTo:language];
[wordlistFilesQuery includeKey:kWSWordlistFilesFileKey];
[wordlistFilesQuery setCachePolicy:kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly];

[wordlistFilesQuery getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {

    if (!error) {

        PFFile *wordlistFile = [object objectForKey:kWSWordlistFilesFileKey];

        NSLog(@"******* wordlistFile = %@",wordlistFile);

        // Show HUD view
        AppDelegate *appDel = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
        [appDel showGlobalProgressHUDWithTitle:@"Loading wordlist. This may take a while."];

        [wordlistFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {   

            if (!error) {

               // Super private stuff here
            }

            // The data didn't load
            else {
                NSLog(@"loadWordlistFromDBByFile -- wordlist does not exist, loading by querying");

                [self loadWordlistFromDBByQuery:language];      

            }

        } progressBlock:^(int percentDone) {

        }];
    }

    // The object didn't load
    else {
        NSLog(@"loadWordlistFromDBByFile -- wordlist does not exist, loading by querying");

        [self loadWordlistFromDBByQuery:language];

    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your kWSWordlistFilesFileKey is exactly the same as the name of the column seen on the data browser on Parse.com.

So if the column is called "wordlistfile", make sure:

```
kWSWordlistFilesFileKey = @"wordlistfile";
```

Comment: That was one of the first things I checked... But shouldn't the key show in the NSLog of the returned object? It's not there... Also, based on examples in the docs, 'includeKey' doesn't seem necessary and it should include that key anyway. I put it in there out of pure hope, but no luck.

Comment: did you follow the Parse tutorial? somewhere in your code I suspect you set KWSWordlistFilesFileKey equal to something? try using the "Find" over the entire project and search for KWSWordlistFilesFileKey ... somewhere in your code you should've set it to equal some string

Answer (score 0):

OK, this was a silly error. I reloaded the WordlistFiles class in the Parse.com Data Browser, and the file disappeared. Not sure how it happened. I swear to you guys I was staring it in the face. I re-uploaded and now it's retrieving, and there doesn't seem to be any weird behavior where it's deleting it.

Operator error.